# Replacing field value with clone value of the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, replace

I have a table with the following fields.

```
Account,DeviceID,timestamp,odometer
```

The first three fields are Primary Key
Some deviceID are cloned in different account.
Now those clones have corrupted odometer.

```
Account,DeviceID,timestamp,odometer
 1        A         001      145
 1        A         002      147
 1        A         003      148
 2        A         001      145
 2        A         002      NULL
 2        A         003      0
```

Device A in account 2 is the clon of device A in account 1.

So, how I can clone the odometer values from account 1 and device A to the same timestamp of device A in account 2?

I need to create a store procedure that I can feed whit three paramaters, OriginalAccount, CloneAccount, DeviceID, to fix one by one all the clones.

**Edit:**

If I have the following data

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| account | device_id | timestamp | odometer |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       1 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       1 | A         |       003 |      148 |
|       2 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       2 | A         |       002 |     NULL |
|       2 | A         |       003 |        0 |
```

After call the store procedure the table must look like this

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| account | device_id | timestamp | odometer |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       1 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       1 | A         |       003 |      148 |
|       2 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       2 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       2 | A         |       003 |      148 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table thing7
(   account int not null,
    device_id varchar(10) not null,
    `timestamp` int(3) zerofill not null,   -- not a great column name btw (it is a keyword, not a reserved word)
    odometer int null,
    primary key(account,device_id,timestamp)
);
insert thing7(account,device_id,timestamp,odometer) values
(1,'A',1,145),
(1,'A',2,147),
(1,'A',3,148),
(2,'A',1,145),
(2,'A',2,NULL),
(2,'A',3,0);
```

**Look at Data at start:**

```
select * from thing7;
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| account | device_id | timestamp | odometer |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       1 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       1 | A         |       003 |      148 |
|       2 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       2 | A         |       002 |     NULL |
|       2 | A         |       003 |        0 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

### Stored Procedure

```
drop procedure if exists cloneIt;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure cloneIt
(   srcAcct int, -- the data of the source to be copied
    destAcct int,   -- the target to receive it
    device varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    -- clean out any old junk in case src does not match dest
    -- this is due to edge conditions where dest has more rows than src, and you said you want a clone
    delete from thing7 where account=destAcct and device_id=device;

    -- now clone it
    insert thing7(account,device_id,`timestamp`,odometer)
    select destAcct,device_id,`timestamp`,odometer
    from thing7
    where account=srcAcct and device_id=device;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Delimiters set up wrong can waste hours. Have them or look into their use.

clone 1 to 7:

```
call cloneIt(1,7,'A');
```

**Test one  edge condition: dest has more info than src**

```
insert thing7(account,device_id,timestamp,odometer) values
(14,'A',1,145),
(14,'A',2,147),
(14,'A',3,148),
(14,'A',4,199);
```

14 now had 4 rows

```
call cloneIt(1,14,'A');
```

**Look at results:**

```
select * from thing7;
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| account | device_id | timestamp | odometer |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       1 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       1 | A         |       003 |      148 |
|       2 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       2 | A         |       002 |     NULL |
|       2 | A         |       003 |        0 |
|       7 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|       7 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|       7 | A         |       003 |      148 |
|      14 | A         |       001 |      145 |
|      14 | A         |       002 |      147 |
|      14 | A         |       003 |      148 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

cloneIt works. It creates exact clones

Comment: Since data is being added constantly I change the INSERT by REPLACE, Do you think that can be something wrong with that?. The table is part of a DB from a purchased software and the designer, I do not know why, call that field 'timestamp', but I can't change it because all the soft look for that column when is running.

Comment: well it won't be a clone without delete/insert, right? Edge conditions. As for the column names, whatever works. We recommend against it especially for reserved words like `order` but you can have them wrapped in backticks

Comment: There's a program that insert data for both the original,in account 1 and clone device in the second account, so if after delete runs and /or while insert is being completed a new line is added the insert will try to insert a line that already exist in the clone account, that's why I decide to replace INSERT with REPLACE instead. That table is huge and very dynamic. But I'm dubious and not 100% sure if I cover all the angles and some particular condition/situation can mess up the table when the store procedure is being performed. I cross my fingers. Thanks.

Comment: well feel free to ask another question or just bounce it by me with more detail when you have it all. Maybe put a pastie.org url out there and talk one thru it for a sanity check. It might need a momentary **lock** but we won't know til we see the code and what is up with data ingest

Comment: It is possible to lock part of the table, let's say, Account 1 deviceID A? What happen if some application try to insert data for that PK combination? If you tell me yes, I will make some research about.

Comment: yes Blue, engine=innodb, sure. **Edit:** user A initiates an update block, acquires it, does stuff, releases lock. user B is block during this activity. There are intent locks. It is wide open for flexibility

Comment: There is engine=MyISAM, whole table locks. Uber safe but depends on concurrency and what is happening. There is no simple broad brush stroke answer without research, and the likelihood of what is happening in your situation